# Seeking/Stopping/Playing embedded flv as byteArray with NetStream

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, flv, netstream

I have encoded several flv's as a bytearray and saved them to separate files. My project is a projector project that loads the files from the local drive so i'm not really streaming.

I load in the file and decode it and save it as a bytearray. Then I use `.appendBytes()` and `.appendBytesAction( NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN )` on my netstream object but i am unable to seek, play and stop my video as i used to before encoding my `.flv` files.

How can I correctly seek through my video without having my NS object flush the buffer?

Comment: Just a thought here but maybe increase the size of the buffer to the size of the data

Comment: Won't seeking still clear the buffer?

Comment: I don't know lol that's why is it was just a thought. If you don't seek outside the buffer then it shouldn't clear it.

Comment: How do you propose to get the length of the bytearray in time for the buffer?